# Method of characteristic for second order pde

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can I use the method of characteristic to solve second order pdes? For instance I canconsider the equation $$u_t+u_x=u_{xx}$$

Comment: The 'standard' method does not work (atleast not for this equation) as one needs a first order (quasi) linear PDE for it to apply. But there do exist generalisations though. These are a bit more messy to apply (one generally needs to perform some change of coordinates). [See for example here (page 10+)](http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_5.pdf) for how to do it for second order PDEs.

Comment: @thanasissdr That is exactly the generalized method I was talking about.

Comment: @Winther Sorry, didn't check your link.

Comment: @Winther the link is dead now. Do you have any othre suggestions as to how I can find what it was?

Answer (score 4):

For the equation you specify, consider the change of coordinates

$$ \tau = t  \qquad y = x - t $$

we have

$$ \partial_t = \partial_\tau - \partial_y $$

and

$$ \partial_x = \partial_y $$

from the change of variables formula. So

$$ u_t + u_x = u_{xx} \implies u_\tau = u_{yy} $$

In other words, your equation is in fact a variable-transformed heat equation and for this method of characteristics will not work (well).

Comment: Where the heck is the stupid downvote from? +1